# What to do with button that have long labels

Tags: buttons, labels

Do you have any best practice on how to handle buttons with long label?

Few options:

1. truncate the label
2. button in 2 lines and keep the width but might be ugly
3. button in 2 lines, keep the width and have the space height for all button
4. ?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Buttons shouldn't be that long

A button should be a succinct action statement:
`Download`
`Upload`
`View results`
`Add to cart`

When the button verges on a sentence, there's likely room to optimize.
How scannable will these actions be for the user?
Is there a better way to organize the information?
Do you need to create subsections?

Let's work with your example (though I don't totally understand the context).

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fblZza.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

In this format, you could just as easily allow multiple selection to download all desired formats or provide a `Send by email` option.

Comment: If you need to EXPLAIN the button, use a rollover on it, or an info icon and link by it.

Answer (score 1):

Are these user-defined titles or do you define these? If the former, you could put a length limit on the names a user may give. In general, people can't navigate deserts of text like that quickly.

If you provide them, shorten the titles to the important parts, and structure them by combining similar options and making their variants hierarchical objects indented under their radio button:

[image: CSV turned into one radio choice with a popup for the field choices]

Try to reduce your number of UI elements and length of text as much as possible, it encourages scanning.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much a design challenge as an information architecture and/or copy writing question.

I look at your original image and see at least a 2-node taxonomy flattened into one level. That's your prerogative, but it's also spawned this problem.

I would consider decoupling the file format and the associated options as the independent parameters that they are. Uliwitness has done a nice practical illustration of this. The CSV options should be a subset.